# Como fazer deploy usando Grunt?

Tags: ftp, deploy, grunt

Estou querendo fazer deploy via FTP utilizandoo Grunt, vi alguns tutorias mas não sei como tem que configurar o `Gruntfile.js` e nem a task que devo usar para deploy e também se preciso de outros recursos para fazer o deploy, como por exemplo configurar algo no servidor.

Alguem pode me ajudar?

---

### implementei

Assim, estou utilizando o projeto Roots como template para meu site no Wordpress, e o `Gruntfile.js` desse projeto é esse: https://github.com/roots/roots/blob/master/Gruntfile.js

Só que não sei como utilizar para fazer deploy via FTP, tem tasks pra tudo que faço no `Gruntfile.js` menos para deploy. Este é o arquivo do meu projeto.

Queria saber como que utilizo a task para deploy via FTP.

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que inicia o Grunt? é um pedido FTP? e queres que o Grunt responda depois de processar? Tens algum exemplo concreto?

Comment: Oi Sergio obrigado por responder, eu editei a pergunta.

Comment: Gabriel ainda não percebi o que queres exatamente. O que inicia o Grunt, qual é o destino do que o Grunt faz? onde entra o FTP? inicia o processo? é o receptor do que o Grunt processa? ambos?

Answer (score 1):

Tente com esse rapaz:

http://dploy.io/

A sua API é alto-explicativo.

Aqui está o plugin:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-dploy

No geral terás que fazer o seguinte no GruntFile:

```
 dploy: {                                    // Task
        stage: {                                // Target
            host: "ftp.myserver.com"            // Your FTP host
            user: "user"                        // Your FTP user
            pass: "secret-password"             // Your FTP secret-password
            path: {
                local: "deploy/",               // The local folder that you want to upload
                remote: "public_html/"          // Where the files from the local file will be uploaded at in your remote server
            }
        }
```

Comment: Obrigado Edmo, só uma pergunta: Em 'local' eu tenho que colocar o path completo onde esta a raiz o meu projeto no computador? tipo:'/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/roots-master'. E se eu colocar a pasta toda 'roots-master' vai para meu diretorio remoto?

Comment: tipo, encontrei outro plugins que da pra excluir arquivos e pastas, não sei se ele é bom, o https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ftp-deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Use o plugin **grunt-ftpush** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ftpush), este plugin você pode permitir pastas ou arquivos que NÃO serão enviados via FTP, através do parametro **'exclusions'**.

Em **'src'** geralmente colocar apenas um **'./'**, que significa que está apontando para o próprio diretorio (src: './') do seu projeto na sua máquina.

Em **'dest'**, você coloca o path complete do diretório remoto, exemplo: **'/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/roots-master'**.

Para usar o **'authkey'**, você tem que criar um arquivo **.ftppass** no diretório que você usar para rotador os comando do Grunt JS, ou seja, diretório do projeto.

Na documentação explica tudo, está em inglês mas da para saber.

Boa sorte